# Why the last testcase is always 0, irrespective of the input provided

Tags: c++

why the output for the last test case is always 0, irrespective of the input. This is solution for a problem on Hackerearth and I have spent a lot of time on this and I am unable to figure out why always last testcase gives output 0 all the time. I get the correct answer or the same input which produced output 0 gives correct answer when the same testcase is input at the first. The code works perfectly for all input except last one which ever the order is. Can any one figure out what the glitch is ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i,j,t,n,p,g;
    cin>>t;
    while (t>0)
   {
      int p1=0,p2=0;
        string s[15];
        cin >>g>>p;
        cin >>n;
        for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        { 
           getline ( cin , s[ i ]);
           if (s[i][0] == '1')
              p1++; 
             if (s[i][2] == '1')
             p2++;   
        }
        if ((p1*g + p2*p) > (p1*p + p2*g))
            cout<<(p1*p + p2*g)<<endl;
        else 
            cout<<(p1*g + p2*p)<<endl;
            t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but your indentation would suggest `t--` is in the else block while it isn't...

Comment: Thank you. But that is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only glitch in your problem is:instead of using
`getline ( cin , s[ i ]);`
you need to use `cin>>s[i][0]>>s[i][2];`
I hope this will solve your problem and get the desired output.
Thank You